# Spilt a bit of mayonnaise on MacBook Pro 2020 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

A bit of mayonnaise fell on my MacBook Pro keyboard and I quickly wiped it off and I think I brushed all the rest from the button seam with a toothbrush.

Could it cause a problem just for keyboard or the device if the sauce probably seeps down or should I not worry?

Comment: These issues come up frequently. For other than a bit of plain water left to dry (sometimes) the only practical long term  repair is to replace the keyboard and have it serviced for further damage.

Comment: @John So it sounds i'm fine for now?

Comment: You can try using it and see what happens.

Comment: If there is a problem it would be apparent. As it appears there is no apparent problem at this time, you're probably fine. Do the best you can to clean up any residue, and then keep your sammiches away from your keyboard in the future.

Comment: Do  not add *ketchup*, since that might create a dressing that changes to French keyboard.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik hmmm, Ketchup on hotdogs is not my taste anyway